# find an element by style with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I find an element in an HTML document using it's style properties?
here is an example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li style='z-index=1;'>e1</li>
        <div style='z-index=8;'>div</div>
   <li style='z-index=2;'>e2</li>
   <li style='z-index=3;'>e3</li>
   <li style='z-index=4;'>e4</li>
   <li style='z-index=5;'>e5</li>
<ul>
```

The question is how do i select, for example..: the element `<li>` with `z-index=4`.
and how to select all `div`'s with `z-index=8` ...

Comment: I suggest reading up on the jQuery selector documentation. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: `$('li[style*="z-index: 4"]')` (don't use `=` but `:` to separate css properties and values, by the way).

Comment: I should ask, if you are using z-Index to attach data to an HTML element.  If so, why not just the `data` attribute, it is what this is designed for: http://api.jquery.com/data/ and it works with selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the style is set inline, you can use an attribute selector:

```
 $('li[style*="z-index:4"]') //returns any li's with z-index = 4
```

see [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). The advantage to this method is that it is very fast.

If the style is set via a stylesheet, you can access it this way:

```
 var elem;
 var elems = $("li");

 for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    if($(elems[i]).css('z-index') == '4') {
        elem = elems[i];  //assign elem we found
        break;            //exit loop early
    }
 }
```

**Note** Webkit browsers, (Safari, Chrome, etc), will not return a z-index value unless it is positioned as well. See this [example](http://restingrobot.com/testing/test.html)

Also, for loop is still [faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attribute-style-selector/5) than .filter()

Comment: I took the liberty to test the two answers on performance, and this one is the fastest. Way faster than using `.filter()`

[See jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attribute-style-selector)

Comment: This only works for style attributes explicitly set, (as provided in the question). See here: http://jsfiddle.net/GN4kq/2/

Comment: ok, again ^_^ , how to do it when the style is used in separated file?

Comment: each function is like for loop ,but when it returns false is it like skipping the unmatched element ???

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a style selector (how would it work, the style is a combination of inherited and explicitly stated rules), but you can filter ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/99Sz6/)):

```
var things = $("li").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('z-index') == '4';
});
```

Now if you are using `z-index` to attach a piece of data to an HTML element you might have more luck using data attributes (cleaner, and searchable by Sizzle).  One interpretation might look like this: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/vMP7Q/1/))

```
<div data-id='8'>div</div>
<ul>
  <li data-id='1'>e1</li>
  <li data-id='2'>e2</li>
  <li data-id='3'>e3</li>
  <li data-id='4'>e4</li>
  <li data-id='5'>e5</li>
<ul>
<script>
  alert($('[data-id=4]').text())
  alert($('[data-id=8]').text())
</script>
```

Comment: The attribute selector includes `*=` which basically tests if the style attribute contains the string.

Comment: In this example, $("li") returns all `li` elements, the filter goes over each one (`$(this)` represents the individual `li`s).  If the condition evaluates to true it is returned if false it is dropped.

Comment: This solution is way slower than using the sizzle selector engine. [See jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attribute-style-selector)

Comment: It is a different solution in other ways too, it takes in to account the z-index being set via a style-sheet.  That might not apply in this case.